# Drop Multiple Pins on Maps, Xcode

Tags: ios, mkmapview

so I have this code which drops a single Pin in google maps on my iPhone app.

Do you know how I would be able to drop multiple Pins to show the different locations of the business?

```
#import "NewClass.h"
@implementation ViewController
  -(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

      MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0,0.0}};
      region.center.latitude = 40.707184;
      region.center.longitude = -73.998392;
      region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
      region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
      [mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];

      MapPin *ann = [[MapPin alloc] init];
      ann.title = @"Brooklyn Bridge";
      ann.subtitle = @"New York";
      ann.coordinate = region.center;
     [mapview addAnnotation:ann];

  }
```

My duplication attempt

```
MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0,0.0}};
region.center.latitude = 53.0838491;
region.center.longitude = -2.7998707;
region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
[mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];

NewClass *ann = [[NewClass alloc] init];
ann.title = @"Making Waves Swim School";
ann.subtitle = @"Clutton, Cheshire";
ann.coordinate = region.center;
[mapview addAnnotation:ann];

MKCoordinateRegion region2 = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0,0.0}};
region2.center.latitude = 53.199801;
region2.center.longitude = -2.89744;
region2.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
region2.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
[mapview setRegion:region2 animated:YES];

NewClass *ann2 = [[NewClass alloc] init];
ann2.title = @"Chester Uni";
ann2.subtitle = @"Chester, Cheshire";
ann2.coordinate = region.center;
[mapview addAnnotation:ann2];
```

Comment: Its difficult to understand this question. You have successfully managed to add one pin, how on earth are you therefore struggling to add another one? Exactly and precisely what is your exact problem? What did you try that didn't work?

Comment: I'm very much a beginner, just trying to get to grips with it and followed a tutorial. I thought it would just be as simple as duplicating the whole thing and changing variable names but that didn't work. Just wondering if anyone would be able to tell me which part I need to duplicate exactly? Thanks in advance

Comment: Show your duplication attempt

Comment: I've added it to my original post. Sorry I'm such an amateur so it's probably way off

Answer (score 2):

`ann2.coordinate = region.center;`

should be

`ann2.coordinate = region2.center;`

So that the 2 pins are not having the exact same coordinates.